# jQuery html script document.currentScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, document

I use html() and I could not find a way to get variables in the parent script.

**child.html**

```
<section class="mod_el">
    <div id="any_element"></div>
</section>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.currentScript.childVar = {
        parameterOne:"ONE"
    };
</script>
```

**parent.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script>
        async function LoadChild() {
            const resp = await fetch(`child.html`, {
                method: "GET",
                credentials: "include"
            });
            if (!resp.ok)
                return;
            const result = await resp.text();
            $("#container").html(result);
            console.log(childVar.parameterOne); //!!!!!!! ?????
            //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        }
        LoadChild();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

What is the possible way to get the variable "childVar" value in parent.html?

Thank you very much for your help

**UPDATE - FIND SOLUTION**
Solved the problem in this way (without jquery) but the result is found ..

in child.html need set

```
document.currentScript.ownerDocument.childVar = {
            parameterOne:"ONE"
        };
```

in parent.html

```
const link = document.createElement('link');
link.rel = 'import';
link.href = `child.html`;
link.setAttribute('async', '');
link.onload = (e) => {
                    console.log(link.import.childVar.parameterOne );
                };
document.head.appendChild(link);
```

Comment: If you're defining the variable as `document.currentScript.childVar` you need to use that same path to access it. So `console.log(document.currentScript.childVar);`

Comment: Thank you, but it will not work. I forgot to write that rawHtmlText is an external file.

Comment: Its all depends on, how you are loading script in the dom, the parent script should below the script you mentioned in raw html file or load after that in case of external script

Comment: Î need variable from child.html read in parent.html

Comment: You can't set currentScript key in script ! It is just return current script element >>>

Comment: Have you tried assigning the variable to the window? Instead of setting `document.currentScript.childVar` try using `window.childVar`. This is due to the fact that `document.currentScript` returns only the current `<script>` element. When you're inserting new html, it has a separate `<script>` element

Answer (score 0):

I don't think [`document.currentScript`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript) does what you think it does. It returns a reference to the DOM element for the currently executing `<script>` tag. So when you assign something to `document.currentScript.someVar`, you are not creating a global variable or something like that, you are creating an [expando property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Expando) on the currently executing `<script>` tag.

In this case, though, since you are calling it inside of code created by `.html`, `document.currentScript` actually is a reference to the `<script>` tag that called `.html`. We can see this if after inserting the HTML we query for the `script` tag after `#parentDiv`.

Because JS doesn't like `</script>` tags in strings, the HTML in the following examples are URI encoded.

The actuall HTML being injected in this example is:

```
<script>
  document.currentScript.childVar = {
    foo: 'bar'
  };
</script>
```

```js
var rawHtmlText = decodeURI(`%3Cscript%3E%0A%20%20document.currentScript.childVar%20=%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20foo:%20'bar'%0A%20%20%7D;%0A;%3C/script%3E%0A`);
$("#parentDiv").html(rawHtmlText);

// This script block is inserted after #parentDiv, so use
// the sibling combinator to get a reference to it.
console.log($('#parentDiv + script').get(0).childVar);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parentDiv"></div>
```

You can explicitly put something into the global scope so you can access it from other code by adding it as a property of the global object, in the case of the browser, that is [`window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window).

The HTML being injected in this examle is:

```
<section class="mod_el"></section>
<script>
  window.globalVar = {
    foo: 'bar'
  };
</script>
```

```js
var rawHtmlText = decodeURI(`%3Csection%20class=%22mod_el%22%3E%3C/section%3E%0A%3Cscript%3E%0A%20%20window.globalVar%20=%20%7B%0A%20%20foo:%20'bar'%0A%7D;%0A%3C/script%3E`);

$("#parentDiv").html(rawHtmlText);

console.log(globalVar);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parentDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using currentScript? As the docs explain currentScript returns the  element which is currently processing. I don't see how (or why) you would use it to get the desired variable. Try something like:

child.html

```
<html>
<body>
    <section class="mod_el">
        <div id="any_element"></div>
    </section>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var childVar = {
            parameterOne:"ONE"
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

parent.html (i think you already included jquery?)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script>
        async function LoadChild() {
            const resp = await fetch(`child.html`, {
                method: "GET",
                credentials: "include"
            });
            if (!resp.ok)
                return;
            const result = await resp.text();
            $("#container").html(result);
            console.log(childVar.parameterOne); // should work now
        }
        LoadChild();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the below solution. It will allow you to parse those scripts inside your dom as well you can amend any stuff easily on your dom.

I have parsed your child.html file into JS dom object, parse script elements and appended into your parent's body element. I know it's a little amount of work but you can resolve your child.html's script errors runtime.

> Child.html

```
<section class="mod_el">
    <h1>Hello</h1>
</section>
<script type="text/javascript">
    childVar = {
        parameterOne:"ONE"
    };
</script>
```

> Parent.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        async function LoadChild() {
            const resp = await fetch('child.html', {
                method: "GET",
                credentials: "include"
            });
            if (!resp.ok)
                return;
            const result = await resp.text();

            //Parse html.
            var parser = new DOMParser();
            var doc = parser.parseFromString(result,"text/html");

            //Parse scripts.
            try{
                var scripts = "";
                for(var script of doc.getElementsByTagName('script')){
                    scripts += script.innerText;
                }
                eval(scripts);
            }
            catch(e)
            {
                //Manage your runtime child.html script errors here.
            }

            /*
            * Append body to our body element.
            * Here you can amend your child.html's elements.
            */
            document.body.appendChild(doc.body);

            console.log(childVar.parameterOne);
        }
        LoadChild();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thums up if you like this solution.